# How to convert gray image to luminance image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I have been set this assignment:

[image]

I don't know what is wrong with my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

img = mpimg.imread('Ca.PNG')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
img = mpimg.imread('Ca.PNG')
print(img)
lum_img = img[:, :, 0]
plt.imshow(lum_img)
plt.show()
print(lum_img)
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run your code? Do you get an error, or an image that is not what you were expecting?

Comment: If you want your image to be in gray-scale use `cmap` argument of plt.imshow. i.e. try `plt.imshow(lum_img, cmap='gray')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine, maybe just a bit disorganized. Maybe sprinkle in a few comments to help you keep track and think through what you're doing. For example...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# Load the image.
img = mpimg.imread('Ca.PNG')

# Take the red channel.
lum_img = img[:, :, 0]

# Plot the single-channel array.
plt.imshow(lum_img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

This should produce a grayscale plot.